# Override DS default layout

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, display-suite

**Using Drupal 8**

I need to override the default DS `"One Column Layout"`.To do that I use the suggested template name: `ds-1col--tools-tools.html.twig` . I have placed that file in various locations and then cleared cache but Drupal never picks up on it:

- mytheme/templates/ds
- mytheme/ds_layouts/templates/
- mytheme/templates/ds_layouts/
- mytheme/templates/

None of this places work, what could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: suggested by what ? twig debug ? i believe /templates is the place and your filename is wrong

Comment: Suggested by Display Suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a comment from @Matoeil , I looked through Twig Debug's suggestions and they suggested a different kind of name for the file. When using **Twig debugs** suggestion, it recognized it right away.

So I suppose the suggestions made by Display Suite don't seem to work very well.